# Can't add array to Matlab dictionary

Tags: arrays, matlab, dictionary

I'm trying to add an array to a dictionary in Matlab.

In Python it's very simple, just make a dictionary and for a key assign an array, but in Matlab I get this error:

> Error using  () Dimensions of the key and value must be compatible, or the value must be scalar.

Basically all I want to do is:

```
d = dictionary
arr = [1 0.2 7 0.3]
d('key') = arr
```

But it doesn't work and I don't understand what I am supposed to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
% create an array
array = [1, 2, 3];

% create a dictionary
dictionary = containers.Map;

% add the array to the dictionary
dictionary('array') = array;
```

I found this alternative by accident looking for a matlab reddit or discord server. And I basically found an amazing AI assistant website https://gistlib.com/matlab/add-array-to-dictionary-in-matlab.

So this solves this mystery.

Comment: `containers.Map` is deprecated now that `dictionary` has been introduced.

Comment: Well yeah, I'm totally new to matlab and it's the first I found at first when looking for dictionnary. Your option works very well! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dictionary.html):

> Individual elements of values must be scalars of the same data type. If values need to be heterogeneous or nonscalar, use a cell array.

So, to store an array under a key, use:

```
d("key") = {arr};
```

Comment: `d("key") = [1 2 3]` got me
`Error using  () Dimensions of the key and value must be compatible, or the value must be scalar.`

Comment: @ChrisZeThird I was wrong, should have tried it out before posting. I'm still learning about `dictionary` myself, it's brand new in the latest version of MATLAB. See the updated answer.